# How can I link to all publisher apps on Android Amazon Appstore?

Tags: android, hyperlink, app-store, publisher, amazon-appstore

I cannot figure what the Amazon Appstore equivalent is for:

```
market://search?q=pub:smallte.ch
```

This simply lists all the apps for a given developer.

Note that I know the format for specific apps:

```
market://details?id=com.adobe.air
```

becomes either of these :

```
amzn://apps/android?p=com.adobe.air

http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=com.adobe.air
```

What's the equivalent to get all the developer's apps list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to link to the list of all your applications on the Appstore use the URL http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=packagename&showAll=1

Example
http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=com.idmobile.horoscope&showAll=1

This should work also (never tested)
amzn://apps/android?p=com.idmobile.horoscope&showAll=1

More infos
developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html

Comment: I need to note that while testing my app today, the new amazon app market app does not take the `showAll=1` anymore. It used to show all my apps, but now sometimes shows one or the main homepage.

Comment: showAll seems to work OK in combination with an ASIN, but not in combination with a package name.

Answer (score 8):

There are two ways to link to Amazon apps. (that i know of)

1. amzn://apps/android?                        (Uses Amazon Appstore)
2. http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?    (Uses Amazon Full Website Store)

I recommend using the first option.

Example: Say you have two apps that use these packages "com.bobsamazonapps.myfirstapp" & "com.bobsamazonapps.myotherapp" and you want to do a search link that will bring them both up.

(notice the "s=" instead of "p=").

"amzn://apps/android?s=com.bobsamazonapps"

use "p=" if you want to link to the details page of a single app and remember to include the full package name
example: "amzn://apps/android?p=com.bobsamazonapps.myfirstpp"

Comment: This should be checked as the correct answer. The showAll solution doesn't work.

Comment: This works so long as all apps share the same unique package name prefix.  It does, however, leave the search string (e.g., com.bobsamazonapps) in the search field, whereas using the ASIN (as opposed to the package name) in combination with the showAll argument does not have that effect.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon offers two different ways to use the showAll URL parameter:

1. With a package name
2. With an ASIN

As reported in other answers, the package name variant does not appear to work.  However, the ASIN variant works fine, at least as a Web store URL (haven't tried this yet with the market: prefix from within an app).

For example, if you search amazon.com for the app Funky Hoops: Free Style (chosen at random), its listing page shows that its ASIN is:

B00DSVS4AQ

If you construct a URL as follows:

```
www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?asin=B00DSVS4AQ&showAll=1
```

it will display all apps made by Solus Games, Inc., the maker of the Funky Hoops game.

Amazon's page describing the various URLs is here:

https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android

However, that page incorrectly states that the package name will work in concert with the showAll argument, whereas apparently only the ASIN works in combination with that parameter.

I'll update this answer once I have tried the showAll parameter as part of a market: locator from within an app.

Comment: Hello Carl, I tried using ASIN to link to the developer apps on the market app but it doesn't work. Could you suggest any other possibility of accomplishing this ?

Comment: @Quaiser: You need to have an ASIN for an app already on the store.  If you have an app on the Amazon store, the ASIN will be displayed in that app's listing page.  Then, you just construct a URL similar to the one above.

For example, all of my company's apps on Amazon can be displayed using this URL:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?asin=B00N7AG06S&showAll=1

The ASIN in this case is from one particular app, located here:

http://www.amazon.com/Word-Solver-Friends-10-Scrabble/dp/B00N7AG06S/ref=sr_1_2?s=mobile-apps&ie=UTF8&qid=1416492831&sr=1-2

Comment: Yes that works as already said with browser but not with market app. I'm finding it unable to work where user has market app install and try to see all apps. In my case, i can only see one or two apps out of my all apps listed in amazon account. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The below link should work - Make sure you replace companyname with your publisher name

http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?s=companyname

Comment: This will work for a companyname that is sufficiently unique. However, if your company is called "nifty" then amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?s=nifty will get you any apps that have that word in their product description, product name, or developer name, such as the developer Nifty Bytes, the app Nifty Driver, etc.